# How to create a program in python that prints the number of occurrence of words in a string

Tags: python, frequency

I wanted to create a code that printed the frequency of words in a string and I did but I had a little problem though. Here's the code:

```
string=input("Enter your string: ")
string=string.split()
a=0
while(a<len(string)):
     print (string[a], "=", string.count(string[a]))
     a=a+1
```

Everything ran fine but if a word occurred twice, it'd say the word and state the occurrence in two places. I really need help here. Thanks!

Comment: [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) does exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of duplicates in a string by using `set()` and only iterate through unique strings:

```
s=input("Enter your string: ")
s=s.split()

for i in set(s):
    print(i, "=", s.count(i)
```

Alternatively you can use `collections.Counter()`:

```
from collections import Counter

s=input("Enter your string: ")
s=s.split()

for key, value in Counter(s).items():
    print(key, "=", value)
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped a lot
Finally did it

Comment: I'm happy to help :). If this solution solved your problem you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. Cheers!

Comment: Note: it would probably be a good idea not to name your variable `string` there is a standard `string` module this would hide.